# PHP get difference between user time zone and GMT

Tags: php

I am using php and receiving a timestamp from the server which is in GMT time. How do I update the timestamp to be in the user's timezone (not the server's timezone) or to get the difference between the user's timezone and GMT?

I have already tried

```
date("Z");
```

but it returned 0

Comment: Use `$dif = gmdate('T') - time();` which should tell you the difference in milliseconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining a web user's time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I think the format may be different because  when  add this to me unix timestamp i get a differenct of around 20 days...

`$newtime = gmdate('T') - time();
$unixStartDate = $unixStartDate + $newtime;
$unixStartDate = $unixStartDate/1000;
$matchDate =  gmdate("d-m-Y", $unixStartDate);
$matchTime = gmdate("H:i", $unixStartDate);`

Comment: What's the content of those variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have access to that information.

The easiest way may be to have JavaScript provide it:

```
var offset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();
// use AJAX to send offset to server
```

Note that `offset` will be in minutes, and relative to UTC.

Comment: but I am getting a timestamp value from the server which I am converting to a date and tiem value in this way

    `$unixStartDate = $unixStartDate/1000;
    $matchDate =  gmdate("d-m-Y", $unixStartDate);
    $matchTime = gmdate("H:i", $unixStartDate);`

How can I use the JS value to update the unix php value before converting? Sorry if this is a stupid question I only just started using php

Comment: @L.Young Have a look at some of the examples in the duplicate question mentioned above. Basically, you need to use JS to send this in a hidden field, an AJAX request, or a cookie, which PHP can then read.